# How can I fix this unfriendly data in either excel or access?

Tags: database, excel, list, excel-formula

I have a large excel spread sheet with a list of data which is in an unfriendly format.

is there a way in either excel or access that I can quickly get the data into the format I need.

At the moment there are lists of names and the amount they sold on a particular day.

For Example, this is what I have at the moment:

```
Column 1     Column 2
Name         Volume
James        15
James        15
James        15
James        20
Michael      10
Michael      10
Michael      10
Michael      10
Michael      20
```

What I need is a quick way to turn it into

```
Column 1     Column 2
Name         Volume
James        65
Michael      60
```

this should be easy right?

thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: In Access (SQL) that would be as simple as `select name, sum(volume) from the_table group by name`

Answer (score 2):

Use a pivot table

1. select your data

[image: Data Selection]

2. Insert a pivot Table

[image: Pivot table]

3. Add Name as line label & sum of volume as values

[image]

*Sorry I only have a french version of excel ..*

Answer (score 0):

There is option of subtotal in excel:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/calculating-subtotals-and-working-with-levels-in-excel-HA001109798.aspx